# Send file to bitbucket project using java and intellij

Tags: java, selenium, intellij-idea, bitbucket

I am trying to send a file to a bitbucket master repository through my java selenium project.

I am currently able to send the file to another project on my local machine using

```
 System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.logfile",
 "C:\\Users\\IdeaProjects\\project\\chromelogs1.txt");
```

However using the bitbucket location it doesnt work, any ideas?

I'm trying

```
 System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.logfile",
 "https:\\bitbucket.org\\noting-automation\\src\\master\\Noting\\chromelogs1.txt");
```

But its not giving an error the driver doesnt initialize, not sure if the url is correct in that form

**Update**

```
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    try {
        //note that it the path contains browse after the repo-url

        String url = "https://bitbucket.org/noting/src/master";
        String user = "UN";
        String pw = "PW";

        File f= new 
File("C:\\Users\\IdeaProjects\\filename\chromelogs1.txt");

        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        String encoding = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString((user 
+ ":" + pw).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        System.out.println("URL Equals: "+ url);
        httpPost.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);

        HttpEntity reqEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()

                .addPart("branch", new StringBody("master", 
ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN))
                .addPart("content", new StringBody("file content, 
can be different than stringbody, just as example", 
ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN))
                .addPart("message", new StringBody("commit 
message", ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN))
                .addPart("file", new FileBody(f))
                .build();
        System.out.println(reqEntity);
        httpPost.setEntity(reqEntity);
        CloseableHttpResponse response = 
httpclient.execute(httpPost);
        System.out.println(response.toString());

    } finally {
        httpclient.close();
    }
```

Trying this now but its returning a 401, any ideas?

Comment: I guess its required credentials. Any error?

Comment: Too many questions.. You seem doing something not how it has to be done.. first of all what does `send file to bitbucket project` mean? Are you trying to add a file to your remote bitbucket repo? If yes why you're trying to do that with selenium? Btw there is no Selenium code in your example. There are two options for you. 1 - use bitbucket API (if API supports adding files) so that you can approach with regular http client supplied with Java SDK, 2 - use git client (either Java client or cmd client) and push your file using that client.

Comment: I have 2 selenium projects, and one requires a .txt file from the other to launch, so Im trying to run the selenium code, and then add the .txt file created to another bitbucket repository, I dont know if its even possible to do, i am able to transfer locally but doesn't seem to be the case with bitbucket

Answer (score 0):

Your link does not seem right. It should start with org and work its way back. See [here](https://www.tabnine.com/code/java/methods/java.lang.System/setProperty) for an example under PropertySourceAnnotationTests.withResolvablePlaceholder()

Or go to BitBucket to find the right link. First click clone and then either use https:// or SSH key in the setProperty call.

Comment: Ive updated my progress if you have any ideas